# Is there some natural equivalent of a Turing machine for set theory?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, large-cardinals

My question is motivated by the fact that (at lest from my biased viewpoint), Turing machines are more related to standard math, particularly PA. But set theory, in most of its versions, seem to go much farther than that. Specially if we consider the largest cardinal axioms.
So my specific question, is: is it trivial to imagine a machine that is more naturally oriented to the kind of operations that people use in set theory? I mean, some algorithm that can decide any question about  any set theoretical statement. Of course, they will be limited in practice by  halting problems, but assuming we have oracles of any level for such kind of machine, will be trivial to imagine a machine that could "compute any set theoretical answer after a number of steps of arbitrarily high cardinality? (for instance V=L?). I image that a problem will appear when we try to "compute" answers for questions about large cardinals that cannot be reached from below; such as, does it exist a "rank-into-rank" cardinal?

Comment: Oracles only make sense to talk about once you've fixed a type of machine.

Comment: I agree, but is there some kind of machine that is able to try to answer arbitrary set theoretical questions mechanically? Once you set one, you'll get your specific set of halting problmes for that machine,

Comment: There is work by Peter Koepke and collaborators on what they calls "ordinal computability", see [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/koepke/Preprints/Computing_a_model_of_set_theory.pdf) for an example.

Comment: The thing is, just about any reasonable way of formalizing the concept should end with "a set is computable iff it is constructible". There have been other suggestions where the goal is to capture $\mathsf{HOD}$, and others where one starts with standard machines but allows transfinite running time. Joel Hamkins and his collaborators have some work on this; not exactly what you are asking, but there are some interesting results there.

Comment: Yet another approach was taken by Jensen and Karp, who found the appropriate version of *primitive recursive function* in set theory, see *Primitive recursive set functions*. In **1971 Axiomatic Set Theory (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Vol. XIII, Part I, Univ. California, Los Angeles, Calif., 1967)**, pp. 143–176, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I. MR0281602 (43 #7317). This is useful in the study of admissibility and in fine structure.

Comment: Another approach is higher recursion theory, which may well be the closest to what you are seeking. There is an excellent book by Sacks on this topic, and Sy Friedman and Chong have an introduction [here](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~sdf/papers/joint.ct.ordinal.rec.pdf).

Comment: thanks Andres, I'll try to follow those references, assuming I can understand them

Comment: I thought about this question a couple of years ago and I convinced myself that V=L _is_ the answer, though it's not formulated in terms of an abstract machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm going to say no. At least to the "decide any question about any set theoretical statement" part. There are well known set theoretical problems which are independent of set theoretic axioms. Any sort set theoretic thing you construct will still operate within those axioms. Coming up with an extended or generalized or tweaked definition of Turing machine doesn't change the axioms of math.

Comment: thanks for you answer, But I find it difficult to understand. When you say "well known set theoretical problems which are independent of set theoretic axioms" do you mean large cardinal axioms? or something else? If that is the case, could you give me an example. Thanks

Comment: I will admit that when I first responded, I misinterpreted your question. But it stills seems that you are proposing a finitely automatized system that can answer all of its own questions. Am I wrong here?

Comment: yes, finitely automatized, but still suffer halting problems. What I really want to know is if you can mechanize all operations on sets that could be even be asked, even those that obviously will not be able to be answered in a finite numbers of steps (they could require an arbitrarily high cardinal number of steps, or either oracles of as high order as you need, which if I am not wrong are equivalent to that, but I do not care about that)